# High performance alternative to std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I work in scientific computing, and I would like to check improvements related to std::vector.

At first, I sincerely doubted that custom containers could vastly outperform the ones provided in the STL, but after toying with the [Hopscotch Map](https://github.com/Tessil/hopscotch-map) and personally benchmarking a 4x improvement over std::unordered_map and a 30x improvement over std::map (just for lookups, because I only do lookups in my code), I can't help but wonder if there are alternatives to std::vector

Comment: Performance tuning is a broad subject. It depends on what you are trying to optimize for. Are you optimizing for inserts? reads? deletes? What scale are you operating at?

Comment: Your hopscotch map offers different functionality from `std::unordered_map`, so it's not surprising that you get different performance. Which aspect of `std::vector` were you considering to give up in exchange for better performance?

Comment: In large scale scientific computing the biggest speed up you can get over a simple vector is to use OS specific functions to allocate a vector for each NUMA domain. Or for each individual system in the cluster. It is death on performance to access data from a different cluster system or NUMA node.

Answer (score 3):

The main area for improvement when a vector is a suitable data structure is the heap allocation.  If you will add more elements over time, sometimes a deque is better (to avoid copying/moving).  Apart from that, the big question is how many elements will you store?  If you have a few groups of many elements, vector is great.  But if you have many groups of just a few elements, something based on `std::array` plus size tracking might be better.

But as you work in scientific computing, this is surely not news to you--fixed-size arrays are very common in your field.

Comment: Note that `std::deque` is not something to rely upon - block sizes range from 16 bytes for MSVC (yes, it performs an allocation for *every single entry* for entries > 8 bytes) to 4 KB for libc++. See e.g. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=674287.